# CSS Bootstrap Dropdown location appearing in wrong place

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have a horizontal navigation bar with a four buttons. The third button is a dropdown, however the dropdown is appearing too the far left of the nav-bar, and it should be directly beneath the 'Services' button.

HTML:

```
    <div class="nav dropdown">

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3"><a href="Home.html"> Home </a></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3"><a href="AboutUs.html"> About Us </a></button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle col-md-3" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Services <span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="ResServices.html">Residential</a></li>
                <li><a href="ResServices.html"></a><a href="CommServices.html">Commercial</a></li>
            </ul>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3"><a href="CommServices.html">Contact Us</a></button>

    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.nav {
    background-color: #171818;
    border-top: 1px solid;
    border-bottom: 1px solid;
    border-color: #E3E3E3;
    height: 60px;
    padding-top: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}

.nav a:link{
    color: #000000;
}

.nav a:visited {
    color: #000000;
}
```

Here is the code to mess around with:

http://www.bootply.com/iSLasxAcEI

So far I have tried to separate the third button into a another individual `<div>` but it left a gap between the that button and the others, and I have tried to make other alterations to the Bootstrap dropdown classes.

I have been trying to have it drop directly beneath the 'Services' button but have had no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

I am fairly new to using CSS and Bootstrap but if their is anything that I can do to help make the question more clear, please let me know!

Comment: Can you provide some code samples? That might be helpful. Also, can you explain what you have already tried?

Comment: I was having similar issue, I've fixed by adding `data-boundary="element"` to the toggle element (BS4.5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered this already. Did you delete the previous question?

```
     <div class="nav dropdown">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3"><a href="Home.html"> Home </a></button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3"><a href="AboutUs.html"> About Us </a></button>
       <div class="btn-group col-md-3" role="group" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"
                style="width: 100%">
          Dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Dropdown link</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary col-md-3"><a href="ContactUs.html"> Contact Us </a></button>
    </div>
```

all you had to do was remove the `padding` and `margin` from the `btn-group` class.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code: 
Add below style code to "dropdown-menu" class

```
    position: relative !important;
    margin: 47px -264px 0 !important;
```

"dropdown-menu" class is not mentioned in editor from your link. It is added in a bootstrap file that is not displayed in editor. So apply above code with "!important" inline to "dropdown-menu" class or add it to your custom css file.